# Diablo 2 - Does Dracul's Grasp cast life tap on Javazon?

Tags: diablo-ii

Dracul's Grasp has a 5% chance to cast life tap on striking. Does throwing a Javelin count as striking?

[image]

Also, I'm curious if the Open Wounds mod applies too. It seems there are a lot of exceptions in D2 and I'm curious if there are any veterans lurking around these parts :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes throwing a javelin counts as "striking". These gloves are just poorly worded. Basically it means using any "attack" and not a "spell".

Sorce spells like Nova are NOT attacks, Assassin traps are NOT attacks, for example.

For your question with javazons, I included two examples to help with judging what is an attack and what is not.

Lightning strike and charged strike will proc because it hits with the javelin (the splits from lightning strike do not count because they count as a spell and not an attack), while a skill like poison javelin will NOT work, because it just leaves a trail of poison and doesn't hit.

Open wounds also counts towards this same rule.

Comment: Specifically, will Lightning Strike and Charged Strike hit? Do the splits also count as a hit?

Comment: Lightning strike and charged strike count - the splits do not. I added charged strike and the splits to my answer to make it exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Actually, it only works on the physical hit that goes with LS/CS, which makes those skills a bad example as they will split regardless of whether a hit succeeds. Chances are at least some will hit, especially if you've invested dexterity for max block - that gives you attack rating too - but not all.

Answer (score 2):

According to https://www.diabloii.net/forums/threads/difference-between-striking-and-attack.314113/

> Striking is when you hit (ie. you don't miss)